# var_dump says bool but returning a string -php

Tags: php, html, string, curl, boolean

i'm trying to check my email with curl.

I've got a function which connects to gmail:

```
function check_email($url)
{ 
    // sendRequest 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    //returning retrieved message
    return $curlData;
}
```

When I call the function and echo it (`$email = check_email($ur);
echo $email;`), gmail sends me some html instead of showing the message:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="-very large url-">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

so i want to then extract the `"-very large url-"` and curl to that, but when i `var_dump($email)` it says it's a bool! why is it returning html if it's a boolean and how can i get to the aforementioned html via php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php says

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
>   success, FALSE on failure.

Looks like you've got `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` set to 0 (false).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 2):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Shall be used if you want `curl_exec()` to return anything other than boolean.